# Distortion of parts of images and parts of images missing during animations in my .pdf output file produced using pdflatex

Tags: animations, pdftex

I have found placing animations in a `.pdf` (Portable Document Format) file beginning with a `.gif` animation challenging.  At this stage my result in having animations in a `.pdf` file appears quite primitive compared to putting the animations in a `.html` file using the programs LaTeX and LaTeX2HTML using the advice kindly provided to me by Nasser M. Abbasi.  Nevertheless here I will describe some of  what I have done so far in that direction and present some problems I encountered.

From a "javalatex" Web page within wikipedia on the WorldWide Web I learned that `pdflatex` does not support the use of `.gif` images.  From what I have read on the Internet at least one way to deal with this matter is to convert the `.gif` images in an animated `.gif` file to a series of `.png` (Portable Network Graphics) images, one for each frame in the `.gif` file containing an animation.  Following the advice on the [Web page](http://modb.oce.ulg.ac.be/mediawiki/index.php/How_to_create_animation_%28Linux%29?).  I installed the free program ImageMagick in a Windows XP Home Edition operating system and subsequently used a command in a command-prompt of the following form to effect the conversion from an animated `.gif` file to a series of `.png` files:

```
convert MyFile.gif MyFile%05d.png
```

The result was that gratefully many `.png` images were produced with names of the form `MyFile00000.png`, `MyFile00001.png`, `MyFile00002.png`, et cetera (Previously I had downloaded something from ImagicMagick's Web site which appeared to provide online conversion of a file from the `.gif` to the `.png` format in my Mozilla Firefox Web browser.  By clicking on "File Tools" right on my Firefox Web browser and then selecting "Image Converter" among the subsequent choices I could have access to that capability.  But that conversion did not work for me.).

Previously I had installed Alexander Grahn's `animate` software package for TeX Live in an openSUSE-12.2, Linux operating system.  I think I obtained it via the Comprehensive TeX Archive Network (CTAN) Web site http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/animate/doc/animate.pdf.  Following some of probably his or else Jim Hefferon's advice I had downloaded the file `animate.zip` and in my case extracted its contents in the directory `/usr/share/texmf`.  Fortunately most, if not all of the software requirements for the `animate` software package appear to be contained in a modern version of TeX Live.---Unless this was done for me in the process of updating openSUSE-12.2 software, at least I haven't knowingly and especially downloaded and installed any new software packages other than the `animate` package to add to my installation of TeX Live lately.

For the purpose of making the `.pdf` output file containing animated figures I followed much of Alexander Grahn's advice and input or else already had commands of the following form into my `.tex` file:

```
\documentstyle[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{animate,graphicx}

\begin{document}
In \hyperref[ref]{Figure (Fig. 1)}{Figure (Fig. 1)}{}{MyFigure}

\begin{figure}

\begin{center}
\animategraphics{30}{MyFile}{00000}{00097}
%for 30 frames/second each with a name of the form MyFile00000.png, 
MyFile00001.png,     ........, MyFile00097.png
%Figure caption here
\label{MyFigure}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
.....
.....
\end{document}
```

Then I executed the command of the form `pdflatex MyFile.tex`.  Following that execution I eventually opened the output file with a name of the form `MyFile.pdf` in Acrobat Reader 9.5.1 and Adobe Reader X 10.1.4.  I think in each case I had to click on an animated image in the `.pdf` file to start its animation after seeing the image of I think a small, white, right hand with an upward-pointing index finger on it.  But after that first clicking a popup window appeared containing the message "Please Note: Click 'sign' to fill out and sign this form," a message which did not apply to my `.pdf` file.  After closing that window by perhaps clicking on an "X" in its upper-right-hand corner, I think the animation began.  I think the animation was executed once for each click on an animated figure in the `.pdf` file.  (It seems like I might have seen somebody else's `.pdf` file containing an animated figure which did not require my clicking on it to get that animation started.  That animation might have only been the drawing of a colored curve.  And that animation might have continued in a repetitive fashion.  If so, I think I like those behaviors better for a reader of a `.pdf` document than the ones I obtained which I report here.).  There were some problems:

1. The vertical dimension appeared to be compressed compared to the horizontal dimension.  The animations each proceeded from left to right.  By the time the final frame was reached in the animation the vertical dimension was obviously highly compressed compared to the horizontal dimension.  And I think the horizontal dimension of an object in the animation may have been horizontally stretched in the course of the animation so that the last image showed an object or objects which were much more horizontally stretched than at the beginning of the animation.  Right now I suppose I can't rule out the possibility that what I saw could be explained by just the horizontal stretching alone without any vertical compression.---The result of either stretching in the horizontal dimension or compression in the vertical dimension makes a circle appear as an ellipse that is longer in the horizontal than in the vertical direction.
2. Although one to-be animated image initially had good color and proportions between its vertical and horizontal components before starting the animation with a click on it, I think parts of the frame images could not be seen at all during the course of the animation.---That is during the animation I think parts of the image could be seen; and parts of them could not be seen.

I suppose that if by me doing things more correctly than I have up to now that better results could imaginably be obtained for animated figures in a `.pdf` file produced from an animation originally contained in a `.gif` file.  Please advise me on how to eliminate the problems 1 and 2 and, if possible, how to make continuously running animated figures which do not require clicking on them to start them in an output, `.pdf` file produced using the program `pdflatex` executing on a `.tex` file.

**Edit 2012-11-02:**

Removing the `\begin{figure}[h]`, `\end{figure}` environment and the `\begin{center}`, `\end{center}` commands around my `\animategraphics.....` command and the `\parbox....` figure-caption command below the `\animategraphics....` command unfortunately did not eliminate the distortion.  I left a `\label{...}` command in place under the `\animategraphics....` command.  Looking at some of the `.png` (Portable Network Graphics) files in the program GIMP [Gnu's Not Unix (GNU) Image Manipulation Program], they did not appear distorted; only in my output, `.pdf` file did I notice their distortion. From my inspection using GIMP I did notice an offset which increased in the images from left to right in the animation. But that might be normal to make the objects in the animation appear to be moving from left to right.  When opening the `.png` files in GIMP I clicked on a button to ignore such offsets, which made the images displayable within the GIMP window area.

One concern I probably haven't fully explored is that the software package animate's producer Alexander Grahn wrote that his package animate requires the program `pdftex`, whereas I have been using the program `pdflatex` on my `.tex` file, which uses the `graphicx` and `animate` among other software packages.  The version of the program pdflatex that I have been using handled my command `\documentstyle[a4paper,12pt]{article}` in my `.tex` file better than the version of the program `pdftex` that I used.  Alexander Grahn also wrote, "Package `animate` supports the usual PDF making workflows, i. e. pdfLATEX, LATEX -->dvips-->ps2pdf/Distiller and (X E)LATEX ---> (x)dvipdfmx."  So that looks at least encouraging regarding whether the program `pdflatex` can also work well with the `animate` package or not.

I request that no one take any of my comments here in a personally critical way.---My goal here is to get a procedure working for myself to produce animated figures in a `.pdf` file when the figures were originally `.gif` (Graphic Interchange Format) files, before converting those files containing animations to a series of `.png` file using the free program ImageMagick.  I appreciate Alexander Grahn kindly producing his probably free software package called animate for use in an installation of the TeX Live group of computer programs.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Some animated GIFs are optimized for size. That is, only differences between frames are stored in the file. In order to produce self-contained PNGs that are amenable to embedding with the `animate` package, the given GIF must be un-optimized before exploding it into the constituent single-frame files. You can use [`gifsicle`](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) for this purpose:

```
gifsicle --unoptimize orig.gif > unopt.gif
```

Now, the numbered PNG sequence can be produced from `unopt.gif` using `convert` from ImageMagick.

To start animations automatically without click, use the `autoplay` option of `\animategraphics`. Option `loop` continuously repeats the animation.

The AdobeReader message you have cited can be suppressed once and for all by checkmarking something like 'Do not show again' in the message box that pops up.

The `pdflatex` command just invokes the `pdftex` binary with the LaTeX format preloaded. And yes, `animate` is a LaTeX package. Thus `(pdf)latex` must be run on the LaTeX input file.